# Unsupported certificate type. Common Name (CN)

Tags: parse-platform

Attempting to upload a new production notification certificate on parse.com gives me the following error

`Unsupported certificate type. Common Name (CN) must contain one of: Apple Production IOS Push Services, Apple Development IOS Push Services, Pass Type ID, Apple Development Mac Push Services, Apple Production Mac Push Services.`

It appears the Common name for prod certs are now `Apple Push Services: com.kylebrowning.youfree`

Am I missing something?

Comment: I am having the same issue is it working for you yet?

Comment: I think it's related to this: https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=12172015b

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook is currently investigating.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/987992644576840/

EDIT:
**It is now working.**

Answer (score 3):

No, you're not missing anything.
This is problem with parse.com itself.
Just wait when it will be fixed on their side.

Comment: Do we know if they are aware?

Comment: I am having the same issue

Comment: Me too. I haven't seen any related post from the site.

Comment: Yes, they are aware and it should be fixed soon.

Comment: @Danko anyone been able to upload yet?

Answer (score 3):

I have also faced same problem.

While we are exporting Production certificate from Apple.

Common Name before was : Apple Production IOS Push Services:[Bundle name]
And Now : Apple Push Services:[Bundle name]

May be this is the reason Parse fails to validate certificate.

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem. Have you managed to solve it?

Comment: Get your s**t together, Parse!

Answer (score 1):

For those of you that did the same mistake as I did:

If you are trying to export the certificate in your private key rather than in the key itself it also gives this issue.

Basically don't open the key, just export it directly.